# Text disappears changing orientation on iphone

Tags: iphone, css, testing, mobile, mobile-safari

I'm getting crazy trying to understand why I-phone (4/4s/5)
has this behavior:

http://www.mkvdesign.com/

In portrait mode everything is fine but if you change in landscape orientation
the logo text and menu items disappear.

Comment: It doesn't happen it in my iPhone 5. All correct.

Comment: does it work well in I-pad too?

Answer (score 0):

Works in iPhone & iPad. Don't see a problem here.